# Assign values to a struct

Tags: c, struct

```
struct example{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

in `main.c`

I can write to this struct in `main.c` as follows

```
struct example obj;
obj.a=12;
obj.b=13;
```

Is there a way that I can directly write to the global memory location of this struct, so that the values can be accessed anywhere across the program?

Comment: Why did you tag it C++? Also, what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: @Jefffrey, I removed C++. i am trying to write values to members of a struct by accessing it directly through the address

Comment: `struct example obj;` move to outside of `main`.

Comment: What's "global memory location of this struct"???

Comment: If `obj` is defined inside your `main` function, or inside *any* function, without the `static` keyword, then it has no "global memory location"; it exists only during the execution of the containing function.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

You can take it address  and pass it as a parameters to the functions that needs to access this data

```
&obj
```

Or, use a global:

Outside of any function, write `struct example obj;`

And in a header declare:

```
struct example {
  int a;
  int b;
};
extern struct example obj;
```

Edit: Reading this issue might be a good idea: [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how)

Comment: why does it need to be extern?

Comment: @thinkcool extern is used to make it publicly available to other files than main.c See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-share-a-variable-between-source-files-in-c-with-extern-but-how

Comment: `extern` means treat this as a declaration allowing other source files to use the name, but the instance is created with the `struct example obj;` at global scope in a single source file.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to accomplish this:

**1.**

Create a header file that contains the following statement:

```
/* header.h */

extern struct example obj;
```

Add the following definition to one and only one source file:

```
/* source.c */

struct example obj;
```

Any source file that needs direct access to `obj` should include this header file.

```
/* otherFile.c */

#include "header.h"

void fun(void)
{
    obj.a = 12;
    obj.b = 13;
}
```

**2.**

Create getter/setter functions:

```
/* source.c */
static struct example obj;

void set(const struct example * const pExample)
{
    if(pExample)
        memcpy(&obj, pExample, sizeof(obj));
}

void get(struct example * const pExample)
{
    if(pExample)
        memcpy(pExample, &obj, sizeof(obj));
}

/* otherFile.c */

void fun(void)
{
    struct example temp = {.a = 12, .b = 13};

    set(&temp);
    get(&temp);
}
```

With this method, `obj` can be defined as `static`.

Answer (score -3):

You can initialize it with a brace initializer, as in:

```
struct example obj = {12,13};
```

You could also declare a pointer to it, as in:

```
struct example* myPtr = &obj;
int new_variable = myPtr->a;
```

and then use that pointer to access the data members. I hope this addresses your question.